# Nhibernate hql left join

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to do a left join like this in Nhibernate:

```
SELECT T.title_id, T.title, S.qty
FROM titles T
LEFT JOIN sales S on
    T.title_id = S.title_id
    AND S.stor_id = '7131'
ORDER BY T.title
```

The important part to note is the extra clause `(AND S.stor_id = '7131')` in the LEFT JOIN expression.

Can I do this in Nhibernate hql or is there another way?

Comment: well, you just answered yourself on twitter http://twitter.com/#!/dagda1/status/28891207063 :-)

Comment: I answered it myself below.  I should have looked harder before posting although it is a very useful thing to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the with keyword, for example:

```
Select q FROM GeneralQuestion 
q Left Join q.QuestionResponses as qr with 
qr.ContactUid = :contactuid WHERE q.ParentUid = :audituid
```